# Flutter equvalent Android-Toggle-Switch

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

is any flutter widget like with [this library](https://github.com/BelkaLab/Android-Toggle-Switch) in android java?

[image]

```
<belka.us.androidtoggleswitch.widgets.MultipleToggleSwitch
        android:id="@+id/multiple_toggle_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:textToggleCenter="Center"
        custom:textToggleLeft="Left"
        custom:textToggleRight="Right"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        custom:toggleWidth="82dp"/>
```

i did try to search to find this implementation on flutter but i can't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as an option, how to use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ToggleWidget(
                initialLabel: 2,
                activeBgColor: Colors.indigo,
                activeTextColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                inactiveTextColor: Colors.grey[900],
                labels: ['OR', 'XOR', 'AND', 'NOT'],
                onToggle: (index) {
                  print('switched to: $index');
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              ToggleWidget(
                cornerRadius: 20,
                activeBgColor: Colors.redAccent,
                activeTextColor: Colors.yellow,
                inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                inactiveTextColor: Colors.white,
                labels: ['YES', 'NO'],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the widget itself

```
typedef OnToggle = void Function(int index);

class ToggleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color activeBgColor;
  final Color activeTextColor;
  final Color inactiveBgColor;
  final Color inactiveTextColor;
  final List<String> labels;
  final double cornerRadius;
  final OnToggle onToggle;
  final int initialLabel;
  final double minWidth;

  ToggleWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.activeBgColor,
    @required this.activeTextColor,
    @required this.inactiveBgColor,
    @required this.inactiveTextColor,
    @required this.labels,
    this.onToggle,
    this.cornerRadius = 8.0,
    this.initialLabel = 0,
    this.minWidth = 72,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToggleWidgetState createState() => _ToggleWidgetState();
}

class _ToggleWidgetState extends State<ToggleWidget> {
  int current;

  @override
  void initState() {
    current = widget.initialLabel;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.cornerRadius),
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        color: widget.inactiveBgColor,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: List.generate(widget.labels.length * 2 - 1, (index) {
            final active = index ~/ 2 == current;
            final textColor = active ? widget.activeTextColor : widget.inactiveTextColor;
            final bgColor = active ? widget.activeBgColor : Colors.transparent;
            if (index % 2 == 1) {
              final activeDivider = active || index ~/ 2 == current - 1;
              return Container(
                width: 1,
                color: activeDivider ? widget.activeBgColor : Colors.white30,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: activeDivider ? 0 : 8),
              );
            } else {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _handleOnTap(index ~/ 2),
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: widget.minWidth),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: bgColor,
                  child: Text(widget.labels[index ~/ 2], style: TextStyle(color: textColor)),
                ),
              );
            }
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnTap(int index) async {
    setState(() => current = index);
    if (widget.onToggle != null) {
      widget.onToggle(index);
    }
  }
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: please share this useful library on github

Comment: how can i set default button as active?

Comment: @DolDurma Check out [Toggle Switch](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch) dart package.

Answer (score 2):

You can opt to create your own switch, the code below is a quick demonstration and I know it needs signification improvements to match the original library style:

[image: cutsom toggle switch]

```
 int selectedIndex = 0 ;

 Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('OR'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.indigo : Colors.grey,
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = 0 ;
                  });
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('XOR'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.indigo : Colors.grey,
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = 1 ;
                  });
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('AND'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.indigo : Colors.grey,
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = 2 ;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

[ToggleSwitch](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch) dart package (based on @Eugene's answer) is now available.

**Usage**

```
dependencies:
  ...
  toggle_switch: "^0.1.4"
```