# change the look of a button after it got pressed?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, state

I am working on an app which makes use of different buttons.
How do I make a button "look pressed" and make it change to normal after I pressed a different button? I am fairly new to flutter and I really struggle with this task.

It should have the same function as the example on the picture.

[image: Example]

Comment: I would use something like Toggle Switch widget. You can search for it, or i found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340682/flutter-equvalent-android-toggle-switch

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean field (such as _isSelected) for each button in the state class of the main StatefulWidget where the buttons exist.  Then in the onPressed method, call setState to change the value to true.  Then you can setup a ternary operator to switch between different button styles.